# I can't import Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I am using Anaconda and already have TensorFlow and Keras imported, and I tried to import keras using the following code

```
import keras as ks
```

but it didn't work instead I got the follwing error:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 import keras as ks

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py:27
     24 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
     25 from keras import models
---> 27 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     28 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential
     29 from keras.engine.training import Model

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py:21
     19 from keras import backend
     20 from keras.distribute import distributed_training_utils
---> 21 from keras.engine import base_layer
     22 from keras.engine import keras_tensor
     23 from keras.engine import node as node_module

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py:33
     31 from keras import backend
     32 from keras import constraints
---> 33 from keras import initializers
     34 from keras import regularizers
     35 from keras.engine import base_layer_utils

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py:24
     22 from keras.initializers import initializers_v1
     23 from keras.initializers import initializers_v2
---> 24 from keras.utils import generic_utils
     25 from keras.utils import tf_inspect as inspect
     26 from tensorflow.python.ops import init_ops

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py:35
     32 import numpy as np
     34 from keras.utils import tf_contextlib
---> 35 from keras.utils import tf_inspect
     36 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export
     38 _GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS = {}

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\tf_inspect.py:23
     20 import functools
     21 import inspect as _inspect
---> 23 ArgSpec = _inspect.ArgSpec
     26 if hasattr(_inspect, 'FullArgSpec'):
     27   FullArgSpec = _inspect.FullArgSpec  # pylint: disable=invalid-name

AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'ArgSpec'
```

I have tried multiple times of uninstalling and reinstalling Python, Anaconda, Tensorflow, and Keras, and it always have showed this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This keras bug](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/17541) says that Keras isn't ready for python 3.11 yet.  I suggest downgrading to python 3.10.